# Angular generated CSS files without filename suffix

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my `angular.json` file I have the following styles defined:

```
"styles": [
    "styles/bootstrap.scss",
    "styles/misc.scss",
    "styles/icons.scss",
    {
        "input": "styles/app.scss",
        "bundleName": "app"
    },
    {
        "input": "styles/debug.scss",
        "bundleName": "debug"
    }
]
```

which generate the following CSS files in my `dist` folder:

- `styles.a24bfcfe902f78294cb5.css` (`bootstrap.scss`, `misc.scss` & `debug.scss` combined)
- `app.c997fa8e46bed6abb5d3.css`
- `debug.6802fb88dae383f6cb96.css`

is there a way to remove the filename suffix?  I need to link to these files in a non-standard way and I'd ideally like to just have the output files be named:

- `styles.css`
- `app.css`
- `debug.css`

Comment: use `--output-hashing none` to remove the hashes

Comment: Yep, that's it, thanks!  `"outputHashing": "none"` in the `angular.json` file works too